# Can I create AudioInputStream from compressed audio byte array?

Tags: java, audio, audio-streaming, javasound

I am new to Audio technology.
I am trying to create AudioInputStream from compressed Audio Byte array, but its not working as expected, its returning 0's only.

Comment: any help regarding AudioInputStream would be helpful.

Comment: Post your code. What type of compressed data is? Wav or Mp3 or any other?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: I am getting audio data compressed by speex codec.

Comment: Code is very simple, I am just reading data from socket and trying to create audio input stream.

Comment: You should use some sound SPI to decode speex. I don't think java.sound can decode speex.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

okay, the solutions is you should decompress it and then you should create audio input stream.

Comment: It's something like I'm sending you a chocolate with wrapper and you are eating it without removing wrapper. Isn't it part of common sense to remove wrapper before eating a chocolate !!!